# Does an API store data that is extracted from an web site permanently?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I want to extract data from my university's server (like grades and attendance) and display it in an Android app. The problem with that server is that it is not always online. So I want to know that if I extract data from the server though my custom built API then does API stores the data extracted from the server so that I can use it anytime even when the server is offline.

Comment: Your question isn't 100% clear. APIs do not necessarily save information anywhere, they are to provide an interface for interacting with another system. What exactly do you want to do, and can you provide an example that can be commented on?

Comment: Based on reading your question, I can't tell if you are planning to write an API or use an existing one … or even if you understand what an API is. You might want to try rephrasing your question.

Comment: I want to extract data from my university's server (like grades and attendance) and display it in an Android app. The problem with that server is that it is not always online. So I want to know that if I extract data from the server though my custom built API  then does API stores the data extracted from the server so that I can use it anytime even when the server is offline.

Comment: P.S. If i can't store data using the API then please do suggest any other ways by which I can do so.

Comment: The API itself will not store the extracted data - it merely processes requests for the data. You might consider storing data locally on the phone and updating when the server is available, if this is viable in terms of storage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure you fully understand the purpose of an API. Generally, an API is simply an interface for fetching/manipulating data.

For example, you may use a web API which accepts credentials and data via HTTP then updates a database, for example, MongoDB.

Another function of the API may allow the user to view this data using a GET HTTP request, which similarly fetches the data from the database.

Think of an API as the middleman between the client application and the data within MongoDB. Hope this helps:

[What is an API?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s7wmiS2mSXY)

Comment: "For example, you may use a web API which accepts credentials and data via HTTP then updates a database, for example, MongoDB." Could you please elaborate this point.

Comment: Your client application could send a HTTP request containing user credentials, username and password for example, and any other data used in order to update the database appropriately. It might be worth researching some details of web services and the HTTP protocol :)